# Actions on Google - Where to find Up-to-date documentation for gactions CLI

Tags: node.js, google-api, sdk, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant

I'm just starting to develop an app for Google Assistant using the Actions SDK for Node.js; I'm completely new to the environment. I've been following this guide: https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/quickstart

However, I get stuck at step 4 under "Install the gactions command-line tool." The guide says to use the command "gactions login" to authenticate the CLI, however "login" is not a valid command with the most up-to-date version of the gactions CLI as far as I can tell. When I run gactions --help for available commands I get this:

```
NAME:
   gactions - The Actions on Google command line interface that you can use to test and update your app for the Assistant.

USAGE:
   gactions.exe [global options] command [command options] [arguments...]

VERSION:
   2.2.4

COMMANDS:
   init        Create a default action.json file
   test        Takes the specified app for the Assistant and makes it available for previewing/simulation
   update      Updates the draft action in the app for the Assistant for the given project
   list        List up to 10 recent versions of your app for the Assistant: in review, production, approved, etc
   get         Get the contents of a given version of your app for the Assistant
   selfupdate  Checks for updates for this tool
   help, h     Shows a list of commands or help for one command

GLOBAL OPTIONS:
   --verbose, -v  Show more detailed output
   --help, -h     show help
   --version, -V  print the version
```

With the very limited number of commands available to me with my version of gactions CLI, it seems like I need to deploy my app before I can start using the gactions CLI with it, which doesn't make any sense to me. Why would I deploy an empty Actions project just so I can start working on it with gactions?

The documentation I found for gactions CLI (https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions) seems equally out-of-date. **Does anyone know where I can find up-to-date docs for gactions CLI?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the [Install Gactions](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/quickstart#install_the_gactions_command-line_tool) section of the quickstart, you should find the appropriate download for the latest binary, `v3.1.0`. The [reference page for gactions v3+](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actionssdk/gactions) has more information about it.